# Automatic typecasting discrepancy

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

float a,b;

a=5;
b=12;

printf("Result:%f",a+b);

return 0;
```

}

If I display the result as float,I get 17.0.No problem
But I display a+b as int,I get the result as 0.

I tried different values of a & b to look for some pattern.No matter what the values of a & b are,a+b is displayed as 0 when displayed as int.

No problems when displayed as float.

My reasoning says that if I try to print a float as an int,the decimal part will be truncated.

Where am I wrong.I searched through typecasting tutorials but couldn't interpret this discrepancy.

May be this is a very elementary doubt but I couldn't reason out the causes behind the discrepancy.I do not know if the title is appropriate.Sorry for that.

I'm a beginner.So along with the answer if you could provide a source I can refer to for such kinds of doubts,I'll be grateful & also won't bother the community with stupid doubts.

Comment: "Automatic typecasting" is not a thing, unless you have a program that writes programs and inserts typecasts automatically. The word you are looking for is "implicit conversion". Also: "But I display a+b as int,I get the result as 0." - what do you mean by "display a+b as int"? Do you mean `printf("%d", a + b);`? If so, that's wrong, because `a + b` is of type `float`, but `%d` is for `int`s, so your call to printf results in undefined behavior. As to the source: read a good beginner tutorial. And be attentive.

Answer (score 5):

> Automatic typecasting discrepancy

There is no automatic conversion of the arguments of `printf()` based on the format string. The arguments of `printf()` after the first one are promoted according to the **default argument promotions**, which involve promoting `float` to `double` but, to reiterate, do not take the format string into account.

> No matter what the values of a & b are,a+b is displayed as 0 when displayed as int.

If you did the equivalent of `printf("%d", a + b);`, it is normal for it not to work, because it is not supposed to. Technically, it invokes **undefined behavior**. The actual effects vary depending on the compilation platform and in particular the argument-passing conventions. Printing `0` is one of the possibilities.

What would be supposed to work would be `printf("%d", (int) (a + b));`, which you can fully expect to print `17`.